# Pine Script Preventing entering a trade in the same direction when the trade is stopped

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

In the current code, if the last transaction is harmful with the opposite signal, it does not enter into transactions in the same direction. So far, there is no problem. When I activate take profit and stop loss in the code, it continues to enter transactions in the same direction. How can I prevent this?

```
//@version=5

strategy('LONG-SHORT', overlay=false, pyramiding=0, default_qty_type=strategy.cash, default_qty_value=2000, commission_value=0.1, initial_capital=2000, currency=currency.USD, process_orders_on_close=false)

pair = str.substring(syminfo.ticker, 0, str.length(syminfo.ticker) - 2)

longstring = ''
shortstring = ''
closestring = ''

toplamlongString = pair + longstring
toplamshortString = pair + shortstring
toplamcloseString = pair + closestring

longcomment = toplamlongString
shortcomment = toplamshortString
shortstopcomment = toplamcloseString
longstopcomment = toplamcloseString

length = input.int(20, minval=1, title='HF')
src = hlc3
ma = ta.sma(src, length)
hf = (src - ma) / (0.015 * ta.dev(src, length))
plot(hf, title="HF", color=#f77002)

ustband = input.float(defval=200, title=" Ustband", step=1)
altband = input.float(defval=-200, title="Altband", step=1)
UpperBand = hline(ustband, "Ust Band", color=#3a0e06)
LowerBand = hline(altband, "Alt Band", color=#174205)
fill(UpperBand, LowerBand, color=color.rgb(38, 166, 154, 90), title="Arkaplan")

hflong = ta.crossover(hf, altband)
hfshort = ta.crossunder(hf, ustband)

long = hflong
short = hfshort


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Take_profit = input.float(defval=1, title='Kâr Al', minval=0.0, step=0.5) / 100
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Stop_loss = input.float(defval=1, title='Zararı Durdur', minval=0.0, step=0.5) / 100
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
longStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - Stop_loss)
longTakeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + Take_profit)
shortStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + Stop_loss)
shortTakeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - Take_profit)


longenable = input(true, "UZUN")
shortenable = input(true, "KISA")
tpandsl = input(true, "TP AND SL")



testStartDay = input(1, 'Test Başlama Günü')
testStartMonth = input(1, 'Test Başlama Ayı')
testStartYear = input(2021, 'Test Başlama Yılı')

testPeriodStart = timestamp(testStartYear, testStartMonth, testStartDay, 0, 0)

testStopDay = input(31, 'Test Bitiş Günü')
testStopMonth = input(12, 'Test Bitiş Ayı')
testStopYear = input(2025, 'Test Bitiş Yılı')

testPeriodStop = timestamp(testStopYear, testStopMonth, testStopDay, 0, 0)


var canEnterLong = true
var canEnterShort = true
lastTradeProfit = 0

testPeriod() =>
    time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? true : false

if testPeriod()
    if shortenable == true and canEnterShort
        strategy.entry('short', direction=strategy.short, when=short, comment=shortcomment)
        strategy.close('short', when=long or close < shortTakeProfit, comment=shortstopcomment)
        if strategy.closedtrades.size(strategy.closedtrades - 1) < 0
            lastTradeProfit = strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
        if lastTradeProfit > 0
            canEnterShort := true
            canEnterLong  := true
        else
            canEnterShort := false
            canEnterLong  := true
    if tpandsl == true
        strategy.exit("short", stop=shortStopPrice, limit = shortTakeProfit, comment = shortstopcomment)     
        

    if longenable == true and canEnterLong
        strategy.entry(id='long', direction=strategy.long, when=long, comment=longcomment)
        strategy.close('long', when=short or close > longTakeProfit, comment=longstopcomment)
        if strategy.closedtrades.size(strategy.closedtrades - 1) > 0
            lastTradeProfit = strategy.closedtrades.profit(strategy.closedtrades - 1)
        if lastTradeProfit > 0
            canEnterShort := true
            canEnterLong  := true
        else
            canEnterShort := true
            canEnterLong  := false
    if tpandsl == true
        strategy.exit("long", stop=longStopPrice, limit = longTakeProfit, comment = longstopcomment)
```

Since I'm not very good at programming, I couldn't progress any further.